# How would multi folder commit be represented in a Git snapshpt pointer structure

Tags: git, file, filesystems

## How would multi folder structure be represented in Git ?

In the book Pro-git on the Chapter "[Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)" you are presented with this image:
[image]

This image prefectly shows what single folder snapshot is. We could think of the snapshots as a several files: commit file, tree file and several text files.

#### Commit file

A commit file as a name(adress), a string author(value scott), a sting commiter(value: Scott) and a pointer to the adress of another file that descrives the tree structure of the commit.

#### Tree file

There files stores a number (int) that tell you the size of the tree in this case, it would tell you that you have 3 files in the tree. Then this tree file store adress to each one of the files store in the commit(blobs).

#### Blob file

The blob file would have a name(adress) and has the text that we writen in it. could be code, and web article or a book chapter.

#### Whats not clear

Would the tree file(in blue color) have and pointer to and address of a sub-tree (another blue square)? Or would all the information of the tree structure be some how stored in the single tree file.

The bellow image is what I imagine a commit structure with several folders would look like, is this a correct representation, if not could someone explain how its actually done ?

Is can be seen in the image this would be a folder: 92ec2 that would have 3 files: 5b1d3, 911e7, cba0a. Then there would be a folder inside 92ec2 with the address ef25b that would have inside it 2 files: 3d4a5, a54fg.

We can see the folder 92ec2 has a pointer to the folder ef25b. Each folder would point to all its sub-folders.

[image]

> Note: I used a methaphor of files but I understand C pointers and memory allocation and I assume the implementation is using C pointers or something similar. Size in the tree would be in bits and you would need to divide it by the side of the blob structure to get the "value 3". I Also understand that Some times the tree may point to previous snapshot of the a file if it was not modified since the last commit.

Comment: I find that font size too small to understand the question...

Comment: I presume you mean the font size in the images ? I belive the that is not need, the idea goas as fallows gray square are the commit pointers, blue the tree structure pointer and yellow the files stored by the commit.

Comment: IIRC each tree object points to other tree objects for sub-trees. Note that sub-trees can be re-used between commits so if an entire sub-tree isn't changed in a given commit it will simply point to the one also used in the previous commit. This makes finding changed files between commits extremely fast.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Sauer. I did not know the tree object ware also re-used similar to the unmodified files. One more question , you meantion tree "objects" in the "pro git" boot the autor also talks about objects. Wasn't git developed in C, meaning a non object oriented language ? Are this objects just **structs** ?

Comment: "Object" in Git just means "something that has a certain hash that can be used to address it." [See this page for a good explanation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). It doesn't imply that git itself is written in C++ or anything like that, the term is not strictly related to the "object" in "object-oriented programming". The objects I can think of in git are tree objects, commit objects and blobs. There might be others that I forgot, but those are the 3 big ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's find out. Here's a folder consisting of two files and a folder which itself contains two files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mattmobile  staff     0 Oct  2 14:17 a
-rw-r--r--   1 mattmobile  staff     0 Oct  2 14:17 b
drwxr-xr-x   4 mattmobile  staff   128 Oct  2 14:17 myFolder

./myFolder:
-rw-r--r--  1 mattmobile  staff    0 Oct  2 14:17 c
-rw-r--r--  1 mattmobile  staff    0 Oct  2 14:17 d
```

Ok, let's put this folder under Git control, add all the files, and make a commit. Now let's examine that commit:

```
% git ls-tree main
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    a
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    b
040000 tree 592be6b15ea6d7060cfcc646a780253c2e7b20d7    myFolder
% git ls-tree 592be6
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    c
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    d
```

Comment: As an additional bonus this neatly demonstrates the re-use of blobs for files  with identical objects. Each non-directory file here has "the same content" (i.e. it's empty) so they all reference the same blob.